# Parse string date with carbon (Laravel/Php)

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I get the date data as string from Google Analytics like following:

```
"20190809"
```

How can I do format with carbon like this:

```
"2019-08-09"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Carbon::createFromFormat()` to parse a date from an unusual format to a Carbon instance.  Then you can format it however you like.

In your case, the following should work:

```php
$date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Ymd','20190809')->format('Y-m-d');
```